# What is the easiest or best way to find the peak in a square 2D array using brute force?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, brute-force

I want to find the peak in a square 2 dimensional array with x rows and x columns containing random values, and the peak should be the highest value in the array and alson higher than its 4 neighbours , North, South, West, East.

Comment: If a value is the highest value in the whole 2D array, consequently it is higher than all of his neighbours, or am I missing something? Just find the maximum value an 2D array.

Comment: Yes but what if there is two indexes with the same value. I cannot control the value cause im using Math.Random.

Comment: If there are two indexes with the same (maximal) value then there are two peaks!  (Or none if the indexes are adjacent ... according to your definition of a peak.) Please explain what you **expect** to happen ... and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force suggests you're just going through the array looking at every possibility. If that's the case, you should just look at every value in the array. Also, the value is guaranteed to be higher than its neighbors if the value is the highest in the array. If you wanted to find the position in the array you could do something like the following.

**EDIT**: Since OP specified that a peak must be *higher* than any neighbors, you would have to add a parameter for North, South, East, and West. You would only have to change the `if` statement. You will notice that I also have checks for where the `x` and `y` loops are because, say for the North, if `y == 0`, then there is no row past that, so we should not check further for the North of our peak we're testing. Updating the following:

```
// changing test case. The new answer will be 4:
int[][] array = {{2, 3, 4, 6},
                 {4, 3, 9, 9},
                 {3, 2, 1, 5}};

int maxX = 0, maxY = 0; // the location of maximum value to start
int maxFound = 0; // assuming positive values

for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
    
        // if current value in array at (x, y) is greater than maxFound,
        // update maxFound, maxX, and maxY:
        if (maxFound < array[x][y] &&
            (x == 0 || (array[x - 1][y] < array[x][y])) && // WEST
            (y == 0 || (array[x][y - 1] < array[x][y])) && // NORTH
            (x == array.length - 1 || (array[x + 1][y] < array[x][y])) && // EAST
            (y == array[x].length - 1 || (array[x][y + 1] < array[x][y]))) {
            maxFound = array[x][y];
            maxX = x;
            maxY = y;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("The max was: " + maxFound + " at position: " + maxX + " " + maxY);
```

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but linearly searching through an unsorted array isn't necessarily *brute force*. Either way, you would have to look at every value in the 2D array, so if you're wondering about complexity, linear `O(n)` where `n = array.length * array[0].length` is as fast as this could be unless the 2D array is in some more sorted structure before we start working with it.

Comment: This is what i wanted , but i wonder what if there is 2 indexes with the same highest value? I'm using Math.Random(); to simulate random values to each index in the 2D array.

Comment: I tested out your code but i have one problem, say if i get two of the same numbers that is highest value and their neghbours is lower , is it possible to print out two peaks in a matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{ 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }};
    int peak = Stream.of(matrix)
        .flatMapToInt(row -> IntStream.of(row))
        .max().getAsInt();
    System.out.println(peak);
};
```

output:

```
8
```